# For loop not catching all intended values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim p As Variant
For Each p In Range("P2:P8")
    If p.Value = "TGL block new" Then

        p.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


        End If
   Next p
```

How come this for loop is not catching all the `TGL block new` values? If any row contains this value in Column P2:to last cell, the entire horizontal row needs to be deleted from the data range which is A2:BL6

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786727/how-to-delete-entire-row-in-excel-if-a-cell-contains-a-specific-value

Comment: Shouldn't you use StrComp(p.Value, "TGL block new", vbTextCompare) instead of "=" ?

Comment: when deleting rows, go from last line to first step -1.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the position of *p* because you delete it and then attempt to shift to the next one when you are already at the next one. A general rule of thumb when deleting rows is to start at the bottom and work up but that will mean adjusting your method.

```
Dim p As long
For p=8 to 2 step -1
    If lcase(trim(cells(p, "P").Value)) = "tgl block new" Then
        cells(p, "P").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp  ' the Shift:=xlUp isn't needed beyond a visual reminder
    End If
Next p
```

I've added some error control on the value to remove leading/trailing spaces and case-insensitive.